# Create ePUB in Calibre without Document Outline?

Tags: epub, calibre

I have a book that's made up of a bunch of .tif images. I have all the individual .tif files, and a pdf with them all put together.

I'm trying to make a .epub file for the book. When I try to convert from the pdf in Calibre, it creates a "Document Outline" table of contents at the end of the book that just lists the names of each individual .tif.

I don't want the Document outline at all.
How can I remove it?

Comment: You can't really as the data you have us all graphics pdf might be the best format here. Epub is text based.

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to remove the Document Outline from Calibre.

1. Select the book
2. Press **edit book**
3. At left under 'Text' section: find the file with the Document Outline (press doble click to check)
4. Remove it (right click - delete)
5. Save

Done